# How to compare a hex byte with its literal (visual) representation in Python?

Tags: python

I want to compare two entities, one being an `int` as a single byte and the other a `str` which is the ASCII code of the *visual* representation (visual reading) of that byte (**not** its ASCII value).

For example: I have the byte `0x5a`, which I want to compare with a string that says '5a' (or '5A', case is not important). I don't need to compare the byte versus the 'Z' ASCII character, which in my case would be a different thing.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are functions that allow you to transform numbers into their string representation, in certain basis. In your case, `hex` should do the trick. For example:

```py
>>> hex(0x5a)
'0x5a'
>>> hex(0x5a)[2:] # get rid of `0x` if you don't want it
'5a'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `hex()` to turn the integer into a hex string, and then you can slice off the first two characters using string slicing to remove the leading `0x`:

```py
lhs = 90
rhs = "5a"

print(hex(lhs)[2:] == rhs)
```

This outputs:

```py
True
```